# Why is “waived” closer to “commuted” than it is to “lenient”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, legalese

For the following question, I am supposed to pick two answers that mean roughly the same thing.  On the GRE, this type of question is called Sentence Equivalence.

> Punishment for transgressions of the law ceases to have a deterrent
>   effect if the punishment is frequently ***_*__*_*__*_*__** .
>
> A. arbitrary    B. changed    C. waived    D. lenient    E. commuted    F. applied
>
> -- *GRE Sentence Equivalence Explaination*, [majortests.com](http://www.majortests.com/gre/sentence_equivalence_expl.php?exp=583030322434243938)

How can the answer be **C and E** for this context? I have chosen **C and D**.

I thought it would be **C and D** because **D** also refers to the punishment being waived.

Comment: The explanation is right underneath the question on the page you linked. "Commuted" is much closer to being a synonym for "waived" than "lenient" is.

Comment: you have to choice two of them. If you pick commuted the why not **changed**?

Comment: "Commuted" & "waived" both explicitly refer to a punishment being reduced or cancelled after it is handed down. "Changed" is a more general word. So, "commuted" and "waived" are the 2 words which are closest in meaning which is what the question is asking for.

Comment: Hi Laser-boy, and welcome to ELL! I've made some edits to your question that I think make it more clear. If I've misinterpreted anything, you can either edit it again or simply click “roll back” above my edit (which you can see in detail by clicking the “edited [some time] ago” link above my avatar.

Comment: As for the question, I think that “lenient” totally fits the sentence, but doesn't have an equivalent word to be paired with. Unlike “waived” or “commuted”, which both basically mean “cancelled after the fact”, “lenient” means that the punishment was light _in the first place._ As for “changed”, it's not a good partner for “commuted” because “commuted” always means “cancelled”, while “changed” could mean that the punishment was simply made different, or it could even mean that the punishment was made worse.

Comment: It's a terrible question. "Waived" and "commuted" have a subtle difference -- waived means it's replaced with no punishment while commuted means it's replaced with a lesser one. But "changed" and "commuted" also have only a subtle difference -- changed could mean a change in any direction while commuted always means replaced with a lesser punishment. All three words perfectly complete the sentence and make sense.

Answer (score 6):

Commuted refers to it being reduced to a less severe punishment.
Waived refers to it being changed to not happening at all.
This therefore refers to changes in punishment that make it less severe.

Lenient punishment means the punishment is less severe but has always been as such i.e. no change.

Comment: Yes `commute` means `exchange a penalty for a less severe one`.